# Not able to move ahead of starting metro bundler in react native project

Tags: react-native, expo

I am developing react native app using expo cli. I installed **expo-cli** using **yarn** with `yarn global add expo-cli` .

I created my project using `expo init appname`.
everything looks good, my project is created but when ever I try to start my project, my computer is getting stuck at:

`starting metro bundler on port 19001`

Comment: Are you able to open simulator and see the splash screen?

Comment: Can you attach screenshot and also try to.open command line as administrator, run expo start again.

Comment: I can't open simulator or make screenshot,  computer is not responding. I can't even move the cursor. thanks